# Method does not exist or incorrect signature - Calling Public Class from Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, class

I'm trying to write test code for the PBSetMultiPicklist apex class shared by Andrew Beyer.
https://gist.github.com/abeyer/cf9ddfec8f9d3bf5f3284f29d5de81fe

Here is my attempts at a test class.

---

```
@isTest 
private class PBSetMultiPicklist_TestClass {
    static testMethod void PBSetMultiPicklist_TestMethod() {
       Test.startTest();
       Lead l = new Lead(LastName='Test', Company='Test', Status='Prospect', Contact_Type__c='Staff');
       System.debug('Contact Type before update: ' + l.Contact_Type__c);

       // Insert lead
       insert l;

       // Update Contact Type
       List<String> List1 = new List<String>();
       List1.add(String.valueOf(l.Id));
       List1.add('Contact_Type__c');
       List1.add('Alumnus');
//       PBSetMultiPicklist pbs = new PBSetMultiPicklist();
//       pbs.setPicklistValue(List1);
//       PBSetMultiPicklist.setPicklistValue(List1);
//       PBSetMultiPicklist result = PBSetMultiPicklist.setPicklistValue(List1);
//       pbs.setPicklistValue(String.valueOf(l.Id),'Contact_Type__c','Alumnus');
//       PBSetMultiPicklist result = PBSetMultiPicklist.setPicklistValue(String.valueOf(l.Id),'Contact_Type__c','Alumnus');
       PBSetMultiPicklist.setPicklistValue(String.valueOf(l.Id),'Contact_Type__c','Alumnus');
       Test.stopTest();
       System.debug('Contact Type after update: ' + l.Contact_Type__c);

       // Test that the method correctly updated the multiselect field
       System.assertEquals('Alumnus;Staff', l.Contact_Type__c);
    }
}
```

---

I think the problem is the need to create a list with the params class. And send that to the method. I don't know what to try next.

Thank you.

=== Solution with 100% code coverage ===

```
@isTest 
private class PBSetMultiPicklist_TestClass {
    static testMethod void PBSetMultiPicklist_TestMethod() {
       Lead l = new Lead(LastName='Test', Company='Test', Status='Prospect', Contact_Type__c='Staff');
       System.debug('Contact Type before update: ' + l.Contact_Type__c);

       // Insert lead
       insert l;

       // Update Contact Type
       PBSetMultiPicklist.Params p = new PBSetMultiPicklist.Params();
       p.sobjectId = l.Id;
       p.fieldName = 'Contact_Type__c';
       p.value = 'Alumnus';

       PBSetMultiPicklist.Params[] ps = new PBSetMultiPicklist.Params[] {};
       ps.add(p);

       PBSetMultiPicklist.setPicklistValue(ps);
       l = [Select Contact_Type__c From Lead Where Id = :l.id];
       System.debug('Contact Type after update: ' + l.Contact_Type__c);

       // Test that the method correctly updated the multiselect field
       System.assertEquals('Staff;Alumnus', l.Contact_Type__c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to include the actual content of the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method requires a list (or array) of `PBSetMultiPicklist.Params` objects to be passed to it:

```
public class PBSetMultiPicklist {
    public class Params {
        ...
    }
    public static void setPicklistValue(List<Params> ps) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This should compile:

```
PBSetMultiPicklist.Params p = new PBSetMultiPicklist.Params();
p.sobjectId = l.Id;
p.fieldName = 'Contact_Type__c';
p.value = 'Alumnus';

PBSetMultiPicklist.Params[] ps = new PBSetMultiPicklist.Params[] {};
ps.add(p);

PBSetMultiPicklist.setPicklistValue(ps);
```

As you are creating the inner `Params` class from outside the containing outer `PBSetMultiPicklist` class, you need to fully qualify it as `PBSetMultiPicklist.Params`.